# Magento old version download

Tags: magento-1.8

Could someone share a link where to download magento version 1.8?
Google search did not give any working links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can download from https://www.magentocommerce.com/download and click on Release Archive and you will get all versions from there

Comment: Thanks, it did not work before.

Answer (score 3):

Should be able to get them all from here: https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/